# SLURM how to get CPUids and max memory of current job

Tags: slurm

i am working with slurm and i want to find out the cpu_ids and max memory my current process is allowed to use. 
Is there a way to figure that out?

Answer (score 2):

Use `scontrol show job -d <jobid>` and look for `CPU_IDs` and `Mem`. The information will be given node per node.

From within the process, you can look at the `SLURM_MEM_PER_CPU` and `SBATCH_CPU_BIND_LIST` env variables if `TaskPlugin=task/affinity` is set, or at `/proc/self/cgroup` if cgroups are used.

Comment: @[damienfrancois] thanks for the fast answer. I need the info from within the job. is there a way to get it via slurm env or so?